# Trying to add info to database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, onclick

So this is my first app and first database.  I think I have finally created the DBAdapter correctly, and now I am trying to implement that into my main activity.

I have a save button listed under an onClick

```
public void onClick(View src) {

    switch(src.getId()){

    ...other buttons here...

    case R.id.buttonSave:
        db.open();
        long id;
        id = db.insertFinalscore("20110612", "91", "18");
        db.close();

        break;
    }
}
```

As I'm sure you can not see, I am trying to insert that data into the table.  I have created an instance of DBAdapter inside my onClick:

```
public void onClick(View src) {

    //***DATABASE INFO***//
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
```

Is anyone able to tell me what I am missing?  I am getting the following warning:

```
        case R.id.buttonSave:
        db.open();
        long id;   <--- The local variable id is never read
        id = db.insertFinalscore("20110612", "91", "18");
        db.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a warning, not an error. Basically the warning is saying that the variable id is never actually used. While you do set its value, you never read that value making the variable worthless. Your program will run just fine as is, but you might as well remove the variable id.

Your program should now look like this:

```
public void onClick(View src) {

    switch(src.getId()){

    ...other buttons here...

    case R.id.buttonSave:
        db.open();
        db.insertFinalscore("20110612", "91", "18");
        db.close();

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Once I remove that line, the following line gets an actual error (id cannot be resolved to a variable)

would i then just remove id = db.insert....etc.. and make it just db.insertFinalScore...